# How can I release the port back in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, port

I have an application which crash, but it holding the port that not allow I connect back, how can I release it back for other application to use back the port? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The OS is holding the port open, since the application didn't use a specific flag when it opened the port. It will be released in time (usually a few minutes).

Comment: Yeah, it's too late at this point. The application has already done the damage and all you can do is wait.

Comment: I can't make the OS to make the decision?

Comment: @TedWong: No. The best you can do is fix the application so that it doesn't happen again.